# Why SIGABRT always stay on main.m

Tags: objective-c, c

in xcode4.2 the SIGABRT always disapear on main.m. I can't get where real it is.

on this line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

on xcode3.2 it work well.

Comment: It may be the case that you mistyped your app delegate class in main.m. Isn't it, for example, appDelegate instead of AppDelegate, or soething? Also, if you're deploying for an actual iOS device, do you have the right certificate installed to run it?

Comment: AppDelegate is cocos2d templete auto create file. It is correct. And I also have the right certificate.I fount more people have this problem

Comment: thx everyone, now I found the solution . Yeah!  In breakpoint navigator, add a "exception breakpoint" for all. it is solution.  Here the link: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/22687

Answer (score 1):

try adding a `objc_exception_throw` as symbolic breakpoint in your Debug scheme - this will stop debugger just in the place where exception is thrown